# Emulating `tail` to stream log data via asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js

In similar fashion to [this bit of node.js](http://www.emoticode.net/javascript/tail-log-output-with-node-js.html), I'm interested in streaming the ongoing output of a text log file via ASP.NET MVC.

I'm having trouble even thinking how I would implement this using the APIs available via the .NET framework. At least, the streaming of new file content as it is written part. *if* I were able to get that data/notification when new lines were added to a file, I could probably just write it to the browser using SignalR/websockets.

Asked a different way, how would the above-linked node.js script be able to run on windows? Any hints as to how this might be possible, preferably without installing any unix tools, would be greatly appreciated!

*edit: maybe something with `FileSystemWatcher`? would that work well running in the background in asp.net mvc? also, that would only tell me when a file changes, what would be an ideal API to use to only get the "new" data?*

Comment: Do you have no other alternative than to monitor some log file for changes?  FileSystemWatcher would be the way to do that, though it would be very clunky.

Comment: I have a long running process on the server that I'd like to keep an eye on from time to time. It's a chatty log, which is very helpful for finding issues if/when they happen.

Comment: Maybe you could throw the results to a slack channel rather than a text file? All sorts of issues with locking, etc whereas you can watch the output live on any device which slack supports.  Just a thought.